# CouchDb get post author

Tags: couchdb

My post document looks like the following:

```
{
   _id: ...,
   type: 'post',
   title: ...,
   description: ...,
   author: 'user_id'
}
```

And another user document:

```
{
    _id: 'user_id',
    type: 'user',
    name: ...,
}
```

How do I fetch the post and the linked user document given that **I only know post id**?

Having user document inside the post document doesn't seems like a good solution as if the user changes his/her name or other details, I will have to update every post.

Another solution would be to include a posts array in the user document and use two emits in the view document. But with frequent posts and high number of posts, this looks a little inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned "linked documents" as if you were referencing this feature in CouchDB, but it doesn't appear like you meant it that way.

It turns out, this is [totally supported](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/joins.html#linked-documents). Your document structure doesn't need to change at all, you can use a map function like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'post') {
    emit(doc._id)
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc.author })
  }
}
```

By emitting an object with an `_id` property as the value, it allows CouchDB to look up a different document (in this case, the user document) than the original when you add `include_docs=true` on your view query. This allows you to fetch an entire collection of related documents in a single query! I'd reference the documentation I linked to earlier for a complete example. (the rest of their docs are great too!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But yes I tried this one. But I am not getting the author document. It is returning me the same post twice.

Comment: Actually now it's working! Weird. I had done the same thing with non-empty value fields. May be that's why. Thanks for answering my questions. New to couchdb. I have gone through documentations but sometimes it's a little overwhelming for a beginner. Plus I think specific questions on stack isn't a bad idea either. It's easier to find later. Thanks for taking your time.